# How can I retrieve the instanceId of a durable wcf service in a portable class library?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, portable-class-library

I try to get the instanceId from a durable `WCF service` using a helper class in a portable `.net assembly`. 
To retrieve the id, I need to call:

```
IClientChannel.GetProperty<IContextManager>()...
```

But **`IContextManager` is not included** in the **portable class library**: 
How can I retrieve the instanceId in a portable class library?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a reference to System.ServiceModel. That is where that interface lives.